# toggleClass within Hidden/Active Tabs using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have an element within an active tab and that same element again in an inactive tab (set as display: none;).

The problem is that when I want to use toggleClasss on that element using jQuery within the active tab it works, but it doesn't when I am on the other tab.

How can I make toggleClass work in both tabs ?

This is my toggleClass function :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#mySelector").click(function(){
  $("#myId").toggleClass("classToAdd");
 });
});
```

For the tabs, I use the tabs JS components furnished by Foundation.

Edit : I can't upload all my HTML for several reasons (size, confidentiality) but this is basically what I got http://jsfiddle.net/rwNaa/

Thanks!

**Fix : change selectors using classes and not Ids.**

Comment: Post your HTML and a fiddle.

Comment: @ShaunakD *and* a fiddle. All relevant code ought to be in the question itself.

Comment: $("#myId").toggleClass("classToAdd1 classToAdd2");

Comment: You're identifying the element by ID, but expect there to be two elements that matches the selector. I assume you're re-using IDs in your document. Don't. Use classes for non-unique identification of nodes.

Comment: Yes, that fixed my problem! I saw my mistake while doing my fiddle --' Thank you!